# Как правильно использовать Long Polling?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте. Пишу простого бота для vk на php, с несколькими командами - должен отвечать на сообщения определенного содержания. Собственно главный вопрос, как правильно получать входящие сообщения, чтобы мгновенно на них реагировать? Почитал в документации про `Long Polling`, там говорилось про время ожидания 30 секунд. То есть я должен запустить вечный цикл, в котором будет опрашиваться vk? Расскажите, пожалуйста, как получать сообщения, чтобы была возможность на них сразу реагировать.

Comment: php у вас используется на сервере, для генерации страничек?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а зачем мне генерировать страницы? У меня же бот. PHP обрабатывает всё.

Comment: Т.е. скрипт PHP у вас запущен как демон?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну да, как демон.

Comment: Ну тогда просто в цикле делаете запрос, по завершению которого тут же делаете следующий (если нужен режим Long Polling).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Таким образом, `Long Polling` нужен нам лишь для снижения нагрузки? т.е. Вместо того, чтобы через обычный API делать непрерывные запросы, мы делаем `Long polling` запросы, ответы на которые приходят реже и за счет этого снижается нагрузка?(раз в 25 секунд или при получении сообщения)

Comment: Верно. Как альтернатива - сервер VK сам обращается на ваш сервер с http запросом, когда появятся сообщения (webhook), правда, не в курсе, есть ли такое у VK (у телеграм есть).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, погуглил, но ничего не нашел у вк. А вообще отличная вещь... Если вдруг обнаружите такое у вк - дайте знать.

Comment: @LNK у ВК есть вебхуки. Я точно помню, что когда шерстил в документации апи, там можно было выбрать адрес:порт, на который ВК бы отправлял запросы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, `Long Polling` это когда вы создаете зарос к вк, и вк "тянет" с ответом в течении 30 секунд (либо до получения сообщения) и потом обрубает соединение, после чего вы снова должны его создать.

Я незнаю есть ли у вконтакта публичное апи для такого, но есть подозрение что нету т.к. это серьёзная нагрузка.

А вообще посмотрите старым браузером что происходит в фоне в самом вк (лонг пулинг используется для старых браузеров, для новых websockets), может получится выдернуть живую ссылку на внутреннюю апишку

Comment: У вк есть long polling - https://vk.com/dev.php?method=using_longpoll. То есть в любом случае нужно будет запускать вечный цикл, в котором при помощи обычного апи или long polling опрашивать вк?

Comment: Да, получается так.